Cuckoo Sandbox: Analysis results folder does not contain any behavior log files warning
I am currently working with Cuckoo Sandbox to analyze PE files. When I submit certain files, I successfully get the behavioral analysis. However, for some files, I encounter the following warning and do not receive the behavioral analysis:
2022-07-08 01:19:00,947 [cuckoo.processing.behavior] WARNING: Analysis results folder does not contain any behavior log files.
I am running Cuckoo Sandbox on a single machine.
My Cuckoo Sandbox configuration is located in /root/.cuckoo/.
The issue occurs intermittently; some files are analyzed successfully, while others are not.
I have confirmed that the files are being submitted correctly, as shown by the task IDs being generated.
i have confirmed also that the configuration of my VM and cuckoo sandbox are correct
This issue occurs regardless of the file's size or type, though all files are PE files.
I have checked the Cuckoo logs for any additional errors or warnings but have not found anything relevant.
Restarted the Cuckoo service and re-submitted the files, but the issue persists.
Questions:
What could be causing the absence of behavior log files for certain submissions?
Are there any specific configuration settings or steps I should verify to ensure consistent behavioral analysis results?
Additional Information:
Cuckoo Sandbox version: [2.07]
Host Operating System: [Ubuntu 18.04]
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
